# Windows Azure Service Bus - A general question

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, azure

Lets say I have a Silverlight application that currently talks to a WebRole in Windows Azure. Is the Silverlight application also able to directly talk to the service bus without a "controller" component which takes the commands coming from the client and routes them to the worker roles in the Service bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Silverlight application is able to communicate with the Service Bus directly as stated here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/servicebus

> Support of REST and HTTP Access from non-.NET platforms

But I'm not sure you want to let your Silverlight app do that, because on the very same page there is the price list for concurrent connections starting at 3.99$ per connection.

**EDIT:**

As Clemens Vasters commented below, there are changes to the price model for connections. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_1

Comment: Ahh ok, so it would be better to use some controllers wich all route the commands to the service bus to reduce connections.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a better approach.

Comment: When talking about connections, the ServiceBus pricing model talks about application-level connections (a connection is an endpoint the app exposes through ServiceBus), not WCF/Http connections. Here's more info on the pricing model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg602420.aspx#SB_FAQ

Comment: Th3en $3.99/connection pricing information is no longer accurate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_1

Answer (score 1):

The [Service Bus Samples](http://servicebus.codeplex.com/releases/view/75077) include a sample on how to use SB within a Silverlight application.